# PHP Upload PDF to Google Drive API

Tags: php, azure, curl, google-api, google-api-php-client

I have website created in PHP. Basically it is a send document kind of project. It uses a document store in Azure I will call and send it into Azure. Now I want to send in email as well as store in Google drive.

So it should be stored to drive with public access. I have create following code. It works properly I don't want any input from user.

```
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $file = new Google_DriveFile();
    foreach ($files as $file_name) {
        $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;
        $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
        $file->setTitle($file_name);
        $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
        $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
        $service->files->insert(
            $file,
            array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
                'mimeType' => $mime_type
            )
        );
    }
    finfo_close($finfo);
```

I want upload from Azure URL using cURL or using API. When mail send it is automatically uploaded to drive at the same time.

**Question Update**

I have function to send a mail this is work perfectly. I would like to store an attachment to google drive and retrieve path store that path in to database.

This all work will be based on API no user interaction required. That file is PDF in formate and not specific bytes its different as per data of file.

Issue :

When I upload a file to Drive original file name is rename to untitled. Here is code.

```
function uploadFile($credentials, $filename, $targetPath)
{

    global $GAPIS;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $GAPIS . 'upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("title" =>"newfile.txt"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($filename));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array('Content-Type : text/plain', 'Content-Length:' . filesize($filename),
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . getAccessToken($credentials))
    );

    $postResult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($postResult, true);
}
```

**==========================================**

Updated code  (Issue with Added code but still getting issue with Untitle.pdf in drive)

**==========================================**

```
<?php

$GAPIS = 'https://www.googleapis.com/';
$GAPIS_AUTH = $GAPIS . 'auth/';
$GOAUTH = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/';

$CLIENT_ID = '709846732498-xxxxxxxx';
$CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$REDIRECT_URI = 'http' . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80 ? '' : 's') . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$SCOPES = array($GAPIS_AUTH . 'drive', $GAPIS_AUTH . 'drive.file', $GAPIS_AUTH . 'userinfo.email', $GAPIS_AUTH . 'userinfo.profile');
$STORE_PATH = 'credentials.json';

function uploadFile($credentials, $filename, $targetPath)
{

    global $GAPIS;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $GAPIS . 'upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($filename));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array('Content-Type : application/pdf', 'Content-Length:' . filesize($filename),
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . getAccessToken($credentials))
    );

    $postResult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($postResult, true);
}

function getStoredCredentials($path)
{

    $credentials = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);

    if (isset($credentials['refresh_token']))
        return $credentials;

    $expire_date = new DateTime();
    $expire_date->setTimestamp($credentials['created']);
    $expire_date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $credentials['expires_in'] . 'S'));

    $current_time = new DateTime();

    if ($current_time->getTimestamp() >= $expire_date->getTimestamp())
    {
        $credentials = null;
        unlink($path);
    }

    return $credentials;
}

function storeCredentials($path, $credentials)
{

    $credentials['created'] = (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
    file_put_contents($path, json_encode($credentials));
    return $credentials;
}

function requestAuthCode()
{

    global $GOAUTH, $CLIENT_ID, $REDIRECT_URI, $SCOPES;
    $url = sprintf($GOAUTH . 'auth?scope=%s&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=code&client_id=%s&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline',
            urlencode(implode(' ', $SCOPES)), urlencode($REDIRECT_URI), urlencode($CLIENT_ID)
    );
    header('Location:' . $url);
}

function requestAccessToken($access_code)
{

    global $GOAUTH, $CLIENT_ID, $CLIENT_SECRET, $REDIRECT_URI;
    $url = $GOAUTH . 'token';
    $post_fields = 'code=' . $access_code . '&client_id=' . urlencode($CLIENT_ID) . '&client_secret=' . urlencode($CLIENT_SECRET)
            . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($REDIRECT_URI) . '&grant_type=authorization_code';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}

function getAccessToken($credentials)
{

    $expire_date = new DateTime();
    $expire_date->setTimestamp($credentials['created']);
    $expire_date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $credentials['expires_in'] . 'S'));

    $current_time = new DateTime();

    if ($current_time->getTimestamp() >= $expire_date->getTimestamp())
        return $credentials['refresh_token'];
    else
        return $credentials['access_token'];

}

function authenticate()
{

    global $STORE_PATH;

    if (file_exists($STORE_PATH))
        $credentials = getStoredCredentials($STORE_PATH);
    else
        $credentials = null;

    if (!(isset($_GET['code']) || isset($credentials)))
        requestAuthCode();

    if (!isset($credentials))
        $credentials = requestAccessToken($_GET['code']);

    if (isset($credentials) && isset($credentials['access_token']) && !file_exists($STORE_PATH))
        $credentials = storeCredentials($STORE_PATH, $credentials);

    return $credentials;
}

$credentials = authenticate();

$result = uploadFile($credentials, 'example.pdf', '');

if (!isset($result['id']))
    throw new Exception(print_r($result));
else
    echo 'File copied successfuly (file Id: ' . $result['id'] . ')';

echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
```

Comment: I think i am missing the question part of your question.  you have told us what you want to do but not whats wrong with your current solution.

Comment: Need to upload file to drive using URL. There is no submit button.

Comment: Do you intend to read from a users gmail account?  Whos drive account do you want to upload the file to`?

Comment: Its my own account.  First is upload operation then read I am still stuck in upload.

Comment: If you are uploading to your own google drive account you can use a https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount.   Note: You can not use a service account to read from gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

going by https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/simple-upload , this should work:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                'Content-Type: application/pdf', // todo: runtime detection?
                'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]' 
        ),
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => file_get_contents ( '/path/to/file.pdf' ),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1 
) );
try {
    if (false === ($resp = curl_exec ( $ch ))) {
        throw new \RuntimeException ( 'curl error ' . curl_errno ( $ch ) . ": " . curl_error ( $ch ) );
    }
    $parsed = json_decode ( $resp, true );
    if (! $parsed || $parsed ['code'] !== 200) {
        throw new \RuntimeException ( 'google api error: ' . $resp );
    }
} finally{
    curl_close ( $ch );
}
var_dump($resp);
```

Comment: YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN i can't find this.

Comment: @VasimVanzara the API doesn't use passwords, instead it uses `access tokens`, read about how to get it here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: I have created Oauth2. Is it possible to get teamviewer?

Comment: I have client Id and client secreate both

Comment: Please provide soultion for untitiled file in drive. File is upload but its name is untitled.pdf or txt in google drive.

Comment: Your file is Untitled because you havent uploaded the metadata first. as i mentorned in my anwser.

Comment: @VasimVanzara well, going by https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update , seems you have to send a `PATCH` request to `"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/".$parsed['id']`  with request body `json_encode(array('name'=>'new_name.pdf'));`

Comment: Its not working could you please check my last updated code?

Comment: Still not get ride from untitled issue. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50830476/5212418

Answer (score 2):

I am still not completely sure i understand your question.  Assuming you just want to upload a file in php or curl here are two options.

Uploading to Google drive is in two parts the first part you create the meta data that being the file name and basic information about your fine.  The second part is where you upload the actual data of your file.

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'My Report',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'));
$content = file_get_contents('files/report.csv');
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => 'text/csv',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id'));
printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

Code ripped from [media upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

If you want to do this in curl inserting the meta data shouldnt be an issue your issue will be uploading the file itself. You will need to POST the metadata to create the empty file and capture its file-id. Then use the file-id for a content upload.  You can find more information on the requests you will nee dot make here  [simple upload request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/simple-upload).

The code will probably look something like this but again your going to have to pass the file id.

```
curl 
--silent 
--request POST 
--data-binary "@c:\temp\myfile.jpg"         
-OL MyFolder\myfile2.jpeg
-H "Slug: myfile3.jpg" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer [your access token here]" 
-H "Content-Type: image/jpeg {"fileid":"1234"}" 
"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media"
```

Note i have not tested the upload in curl this is just a guess.

Comment: can you share an example.

Comment: I have shared the example code that i have.  With regard to your update: Your going to have to login a user in read their gmail and then upload to their google drive account.  All this will have to be done authenticated to google drive and gmail.   You cant access a users private data without being authenticated first.

Comment: I have created credential.js its proper.

Comment: once you have authenticated you can use the access token in the curl code above.   If you decide to use php then just let it handel the authentication as shown in the php quick start https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php

Comment: Please provide soultion for untitiled file in drive. File is upload but its name is untitled.pdf or txt in google drive.

Comment: how to set file name in CURL request for .

Answer (score 1):

You can use Logic Apps to send the file from Azure Blob storage to Google Drive as well as an email attachment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage

Alternatively files stored in Azure Blobs can be addresses with a public URL assuming you have the right permissions set on the container and/or blob.

Comment: Please provide soultion for untitiled file in drive. File is upload but its name is untitled.pdf or txt in google drive.