# Uploaded file rename to untitled Google drive

Tags: php

I have done google api integration code as well as file is upload to a drive. I have issue regarding a uploaded file name is **"Untitled"**. Please review code and guide me what is missing.

```
<?php

$GAPIS = 'https://www.googleapis.com/';
$GAPIS_AUTH = $GAPIS . 'auth/';
$GOAUTH = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/';

$CLIENT_ID = '709846732498-t19mhuuvq0nqtng5ogg8XXXXXX0im8.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXKa';
$REDIRECT_URI = 'http' . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80 ? '' : 's') . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$SCOPES = array($GAPIS_AUTH . 'drive', $GAPIS_AUTH . 'drive.file', $GAPIS_AUTH . 'userinfo.email', $GAPIS_AUTH . 'userinfo.profile');
$STORE_PATH = 'credentials.json';

function uploadFile($credentials, $filename, $targetPath)
{

    global $GAPIS;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $GAPIS . 'upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media');

   //$content =  { title  "mypdf.pdf", description = "mypdf.pdf", mimeType = "application/pdf" };

   $contentArry = array('title' =>'veridoc' );
   $contentArry = json_encode($contentArry);



    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$contentArry);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($filename));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array('Content-Type : application/pdf','Content-Length:' . filesize($filename),'Authorization: Bearer ' . getAccessToken($credentials))
    );

    $postResult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($postResult, true);
}

function getStoredCredentials($path)
{

    $credentials = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);

    if (isset($credentials['refresh_token']))
        return $credentials;

    $expire_date = new DateTime();
    $expire_date->setTimestamp($credentials['created']);
    $expire_date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $credentials['expires_in'] . 'S'));

    $current_time = new DateTime();

    if ($current_time->getTimestamp() >= $expire_date->getTimestamp())
    {
        $credentials = null;
        unlink($path);
    }

    return $credentials;
}

function storeCredentials($path, $credentials)
{

    $credentials['created'] = (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
    file_put_contents($path, json_encode($credentials));
    return $credentials;
}

function requestAuthCode()
{

    global $GOAUTH, $CLIENT_ID, $REDIRECT_URI, $SCOPES;
    $url = sprintf($GOAUTH . 'auth?scope=%s&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=code&client_id=%s&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline',
            urlencode(implode(' ', $SCOPES)), urlencode($REDIRECT_URI), urlencode($CLIENT_ID)
    );
    header('Location:' . $url);
}

function requestAccessToken($access_code)
{

    global $GOAUTH, $CLIENT_ID, $CLIENT_SECRET, $REDIRECT_URI;
    $url = $GOAUTH . 'token';
    $post_fields = 'code=' . $access_code . '&client_id=' . urlencode($CLIENT_ID) . '&client_secret=' . urlencode($CLIENT_SECRET)
            . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($REDIRECT_URI) . '&grant_type=authorization_code';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}

function getAccessToken($credentials)
{

    $expire_date = new DateTime();
    $expire_date->setTimestamp($credentials['created']);
    $expire_date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $credentials['expires_in'] . 'S'));

    $current_time = new DateTime();

    if ($current_time->getTimestamp() >= $expire_date->getTimestamp())
        return $credentials['refresh_token'];
    else
        return $credentials['access_token'];

}

function authenticate()
{

    global $STORE_PATH;

    if (file_exists($STORE_PATH))
        $credentials = getStoredCredentials($STORE_PATH);
    else
        $credentials = null;

    if (!(isset($_GET['code']) || isset($credentials)))
        requestAuthCode();

    if (!isset($credentials))
        $credentials = requestAccessToken($_GET['code']);

    if (isset($credentials) && isset($credentials['access_token']) && !file_exists($STORE_PATH))
        $credentials = storeCredentials($STORE_PATH, $credentials);

    return $credentials;
}   

$credentials = authenticate();

$result = uploadFile($credentials, 'veridoc.pdf', '');

if (!isset($result['id']))
    throw new Exception(print_r($result));
else
    echo 'File copied successfuly (file Id: ' . $result['id'] . ')';

echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);

`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

going by the documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update , to rename a file, do a PATCH request to `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<fileId>` with the new name, in your case, i guess that would be

```
$postResult = curl_exec ( $ch );
$parsed = json_decode ( $postResult, true );
if (! $parsed || $parsed ['code'] !== 200) {
    throw new \RuntimeException ( 'google api error: ' . $postResult );
}
$id = $parsed ['id']; // ?? wait, is it id or fileId?
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' . urlencode ( $id ),
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode ( array (
                'name' => basename ( $filename ) 
        ) ),
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                'Content-Type : application/json',
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . getAccessToken ( $credentials ) 
        ) 

) );
curl_exec($ch);
```

ps, don't set the `Content-Length` header manually when using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, because curl will do it for you, and if you're using multipart/form-data, the length you set yourself is very likely to be wrong even (doesn't concern your code as you're not using multipart/form-data, but it's a good habit to learn nonetheless, get rid of it.)

Comment: You are hero. !! Finally get ride from this.

Comment: Need little more help one last time : https://stackoverflow.com/q/50856095/5212418