# Create folder in root directiry of and upload file to that folder google drive api

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I want to create folder in googledrive root directory using CURL. File is uploaded to drive but I need to create a folder and upload file to that folder.

**As per @hanshenrik Code Create Folder is working Move file is not work**

**My Updated code :**

```
$REDIRECT_URI = 'http' . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80 ? '' : 's') . '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$SCOPES = array($GAPIS_AUTH . 'drive', $GAPIS_AUTH . 'drive.file', $GAPIS_AUTH . 'userinfo.email', $GAPIS_AUTH . 'userinfo.profile');
$STORE_PATH = 'credentials.json';

function uploadFile($credentials, $filename, $targetPath,$folderId)
{

    global $GAPIS;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $GAPIS . 'upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media');

   //$content =  { title  "mypdf.pdf", description = "mypdf.pdf", mimeType = "application/pdf" };

   $contentArry = array('name' =>'veridoc', 'parents' => array('17dVe2GYpaHYFdFn1by5-TYKU1LXSAwkp'));
   $contentArry = json_encode($contentArry);



    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$contentArry);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($filename));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array('Content-Type : application/pdf','Content-Length:' . filesize($filename),'Authorization: Bearer ' . getAccessToken($credentials))
    );

    $postResult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($postResult, true);
}
function RenameUploadedFile($id,$credentials,$filename)
{

 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' . urlencode ( $id ),
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode ( array (
                    'name' => $filename  
            ) ),
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                    'Content-Type : application/json',
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . getAccessToken ( $credentials ) 
            ) 

    ) );
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return true;
}

  function CreateGDFolder($credentials,$foldername)
    {


            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array ( $curl, array (
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files',
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,             
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode ( array (
                // Earlier it was title changed to name
                "name" => $foldername,
                "mimeType" => "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"

            ) ),
            // Earlier it was PATCH changed to post
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                'Content-Type : application/json',
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . getAccessToken ( $credentials ) 
            ) 

            ) );

           $response = curl_exec($curl);

        return json_decode($response, true);
}



function getStoredCredentials($path)
{

    $credentials = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);

    if (isset($credentials['refresh_token']))
    {   
        return $credentials;
    }


    $expire_date = new DateTime();
    $expire_date->setTimestamp($credentials['created']);
    $expire_date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $credentials['expires_in'] . 'S'));

    $current_time = new DateTime();

    if ($current_time->getTimestamp() >= $expire_date->getTimestamp())
    {
        $credentials = null;
        unlink($path);
    }

    return $credentials;
}

function storeCredentials($path, $credentials)
{

    $credentials['created'] = (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
    file_put_contents($path, json_encode($credentials));
    return $credentials;
}

function requestAuthCode()
{

    global $GOAUTH, $CLIENT_ID, $REDIRECT_URI, $SCOPES;
    $url = sprintf($GOAUTH . 'auth?scope=%s&redirect_uri=%s&response_type=code&client_id=%s&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline',
            urlencode(implode(' ', $SCOPES)), urlencode($REDIRECT_URI), urlencode($CLIENT_ID)
    );
    header('Location:' . $url);
}

function requestAccessToken($access_code)
{

    global $GOAUTH, $CLIENT_ID, $CLIENT_SECRET, $REDIRECT_URI;
    $url = $GOAUTH . 'token';
    $post_fields = 'code=' . $access_code . '&client_id=' . urlencode($CLIENT_ID) . '&client_secret=' . urlencode($CLIENT_SECRET)
            . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($REDIRECT_URI) . '&grant_type=authorization_code';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}

function getAccessToken($credentials)
{

    $expire_date = new DateTime();
    $expire_date->setTimestamp($credentials['created']);
    $expire_date->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $credentials['expires_in'] . 'S'));

    $current_time = new DateTime();

    if ($current_time->getTimestamp() >= $expire_date->getTimestamp())
        return $credentials['refresh_token'];
    else
        return $credentials['access_token'];

}

function authenticate()
{

    global $STORE_PATH;

    if (file_exists($STORE_PATH))
        $credentials = getStoredCredentials($STORE_PATH);
    else
        $credentials = null;

    if (!(isset($_GET['code']) || isset($credentials)))
        requestAuthCode();

    if (!isset($credentials))
        $credentials = requestAccessToken($_GET['code']);

    if (isset($credentials) && isset($credentials['access_token']) && !file_exists($STORE_PATH))
        $credentials = storeCredentials($STORE_PATH, $credentials);

    return $credentials;
}   

$credentials = authenticate();

$folderresponse=CreateGDFolder($credentials,"veridoc");
$folderID= $folderresponse['id'];
$folder_id=$folderID;
$filename="veridoc".date('_Y_m_d_H_i_s').".pdf";

$result = uploadFile($credentials, 'veridoc.pdf', '',$folderID);

// File rename to original

$id=$result['id'];
$file_id=$id;


if(isset($folderID)){

//Upload a file 
if(RenameUploadedFile($id,$credentials,$filename))
{
echo "We have uploaded ".$filename." to drive";
}
else{
echo "can't rename file";
}
}



try {
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/' . urlencode ( $file_id ),
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode (array(
            'addParents' => $folder_id,
            'removeParents' => 'root',
            'fields' => 'id, parents') ),
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                    'Content-Type : application/pdf',
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . getAccessToken ( $credentials ) 
            ) 

    ) );
    $resp = curl_exec ( $ch );
    $parsed = json_decode ( $resp, true );

} finally{
    curl_close ( $ch );
}
```

Comment: First create folder and get the id after that while uploading the file you can pass the id in the parents parameter.

Comment: No, its not like that.

Comment: I need to create a folder in root

Comment: Don't pass the parents parameter when creating folder.

Comment: the bug making your request different from the request you state you want to send, is that you're not putting `{"id":"0ADK06pfg"}` in a numerically-indexed array. `"parents" => array( 0 => array("id" => "0ADoIbPC84gk7Uk9PVA") )`  would fix that. when json_encode encounters a numerically indexed array, it will create a json array, but when it encounters a not-numerically-indexed array, it will create a json object

Comment: @hanshenrik I want to create a website still issue with credential is expried every time as well as folder not create yet.I have tried all solution.

Comment: @VasimVanzara may I know what error or problems you are facing. We have shared all the possible information regarding your problem. And first of all you should use the v3 api here you are using the v2

Comment: @Wellwisher folder is not creating. I have tried v3 and v2 both.

Comment: I have made some changes on your code. its working fine.

Comment: let me check code

Comment: @hanshenrik https://stackoverflow.com/a/50927468/5212418

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my working example:

**To connect Google Driver:**

```
public function connect(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setHttpClient(new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]));
        $client->setClientId('xxxx');
        $client->setClientSecret('xxxxxx');
        $client->setRedirectUri(url('copywriter/connect'));
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
        $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder'));
        if (isset($request->code)) {
            $authCode = trim($request->code);
            $accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);
            $copywriter->gd_access_token=json_encode($accessToken, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            $copywriter->save();
        } else {
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            return redirect($authUrl);
        }

        $found=$this->search_gd("files");
        if (!isset($found['file_id'])) {
            $found=$this->create_folder_gd("copify_files");
            $copywriter->gd_folder_id=$found["file_id"];
            $copywriter->save();
        }
        return redirect(route("copywriter.index"));
    }
```

**Send to Google Drive**

```
    public function send_to_gd($name)
        {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $copywriter=Copywriter::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
            $folderId = $copywriter->gd_folder_id;
            $client=$this->getClient();
            $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
            $fileMetadata = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
            'name' => $name,'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.document','parents' => array($folderId)));
            $file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
            'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
            'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            'fields' => 'id'));
            return $file->id;
        }
```

**Client of Request:**

```
public function getClient($user=null)
    {
        if ($user==null) {
            $user = Auth::user();
        }
        $copywriter=Copywriter::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setHttpClient(new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]));
        $client->setClientId('xxxx');
        $client->setClientSecret('xxxxx');
        $client->setRedirectUri(url('copywriter/connect'));
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
        $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder'));


        $data=json_decode($copywriter->gd_access_token, true);

        $client->setAccessToken($data);

        // Refresh the token if it's expired.
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $oldAccessToken=$client->getAccessToken();
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            $accessToken=$client->getAccessToken();
            $accessToken['refresh_token']=$oldAccessToken['refresh_token'];

            $copywriter->gd_access_token=json_encode($accessToken, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            $copywriter->save();
        }
        return $client;
    }
```

**Search in Google Drive**

```
public function search_gd($name)
    {
        $client=$this->getClient();
        $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $pageToken = null;
        do {
            $response = $service->files->listFiles(array(
        'q' => "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='".$name."'",
        'spaces' => 'drive',
        'pageToken' => $pageToken,
        'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    ));
            foreach ($response->files as $file) {
                return ['file_name'=>$file->name,'file_id'=>$file->id];
                printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n", $file->name, $file->id);
            }
            if (isset($repsonse)) {
                $pageToken = $repsonse->pageToken;
            }
        } while ($pageToken != null);
    }
```

**Create a folder on Google Drive**

```
public function create_folder_gd($name)
    {
        $client=$this->getClient();
        $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $fileMetadata = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => $name,
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));
        $file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'fields' => 'id'));
        return ['file_name'=>$name,'file_id'=>$file->id];
    }
```

**Create a document on Google Drive:**

```
public function create_document($name, $content_id=null)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $copywriter=Copywriter::where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
        $folderId = $copywriter->gd_folder_id;
        $client=$this->getClient();
        $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $fileMetadata = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
      'name' => $name,'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.document','parents' => array($folderId)));
        $file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
      'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
      'uploadType' => 'multipart',
      'fields' => 'id'));
        if ($content_id!=null) {
            $content=Content::findOrFail($content_id);
            $content->file_id=$file->id;
            $content->save();
        }
        return ['file_name'=>$name,'file_id'=>$file->id];
    }
```

My Models is **Copywriter** and **Content** replace it with your's.

Answer (score 2):

This will help You:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder

**Creating a folder:**

In the Drive API, a folder is essentially a file — one identified by the special folder MIME type application/vnd.google-apps.folder. You can create a new folder by inserting a file with this MIME type and a folder title. Do not include an extension when setting a folder title.

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'Invoices',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'));
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'fields' => 'id'));
printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

**Inserting a file in a folder:**

To insert a file in a particular folder, specify the correct ID in the parents property of the file, as shown:

```
$folderId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1TGRPeTVjaWRDY1E';
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'photo.jpg',
    'parents' => array($folderId)
));
$content = file_get_contents('files/photo.jpg');
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id'));
printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

The parents property can be used when creating a folder as well to create a subfolder.

**Moving files between folders:**
To add or remove parents for an exiting file, use the addParents and removeParents query parameters on the files.[update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) method.

Both parameters may be used to move a file from one folder to another, as shown:

```
$fileId = '1sTWaJ_j7PkjzaBWtNc3IzovK5hQf21FbOw9yLeeLPNQ';
$folderId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1TGRPeTVjaWRDY1E';
$emptyFileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
// Retrieve the existing parents to remove
$file = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array('fields' => 'parents'));
$previousParents = join(',', $file->parents);
// Move the file to the new folder
$file = $driveService->files->update($fileId, $emptyFileMetadata, array(
    'addParents' => $folderId,
    'removeParents' => $previousParents,
    'fields' => 'id, parents'));
```

Answer (score 2):

going by the documentation on folders here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/folder , seems like you create folders by uploading an empty "file" with the content-type set to `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`.

here is documentation on how to upload files, in a simple way: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/simple-upload

problem with that upload method is the the created file (or folder, in this case) won't have a name, it will just be called `untitled<whatever>`, so finally, here's documentation on how to rename files: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update (or in this case, a folder)

putting it all together, you'll probably end up with something like:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                'Content-Type: application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
                'Authorization: Bearer '.getAccessToken ( $credentials )  
        ),
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '', // "empty file"
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1 
) );
try {
    // this will create the folder, with no name
    if (false === ($resp = curl_exec ( $ch ))) {
        throw new \RuntimeException ( 'curl error ' . curl_errno ( $ch ) . ": " . curl_error ( $ch ) );
    }
    $parsed = json_decode ( $resp, true );
    if (! $parsed || $parsed ['code'] !== 200) {
        throw new \RuntimeException ( 'google api error: ' . $resp );
    }
    $id = $parsed ['id'];
    // now to give the folder a name:
    curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' . urlencode ( $id ),
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode ( array (
                    'name' => 'the_folders_name' 
            ) ),
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                    'Content-Type : application/json',
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . getAccessToken ( $credentials ) 
            ) 

    ) );

    if (false === ($resp = curl_exec ( $ch ))) {
        throw new \RuntimeException ( 'curl error ' . curl_errno ( $ch ) . ": " . curl_error ( $ch ) );
    }
    $parsed = json_decode ( $resp, true );
    if (! $parsed || $parsed ['code'] !== 200) {
        throw new \RuntimeException ( 'google api error: ' . $resp );
    }
} finally{
    curl_close ( $ch );
}
var_dump ( $resp );
```

and finally, to move files inside this folder, send a PATCH request to `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/<file_you_want_to_move_id>` with the folder's id as the `addParents` parameter of the request body, eg something like:

```
<?php
try {
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/' . urlencode ( $file_id ),
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode ( array (
                    'addParents' => $folder_id,
                    'removeParents'=> 'root',


            ) ),
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PATCH',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                    'Content-Type : application/json',
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . getAccessToken ( $credentials ) 
            ) 

    ) );
    if (false === ($resp = curl_exec ( $ch ))) {
        throw new \RuntimeException ( 'curl error ' . curl_errno ( $ch ) . ": " . curl_error ( $ch ) );
    }
    $parsed = json_decode ( $resp, true );
    if (! $parsed || $parsed ['code'] !== 200) {
        throw new \RuntimeException ( 'google api error: ' . $resp );
    }
} finally{
    curl_close ( $ch );
}
```

Comment: Is it add file also?

Comment: @VasimVanzara sorry, forgot about that, now i updated my answer to add a section about how to move files inside folders.

Comment: No I mean upload to that folder/

Comment: This is for move

Comment: @VasimVanzara you can just move the file to the folder immediately after uploading it, you know. you can even do it in the same request that you give the file a name, `json_encode(array("name"=>"filename.pdf","addParents"=>"folder_id","removeParents"=>"root"))`

Comment: let me check with this one

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: google api error: 1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/uploadtodrive/index.php:263 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/uploadtodrive/index.php on line 263

Comment: @VasimVanzara check the gdrive, was the file actually moved?

Comment: Code is update in question create folder is working still move is not working

Answer (score 0):

See this if it is working. I have made changes like `"name" => ""`, `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',`

```
function CreateGDFolder($credentials)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files',
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode ( array (
            // Earlier it was title changed to name
            "name" => "pets",
            "mimeType" => "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"

        ) ),
        // Earlier it was PATCH changed to post
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
            'Content-Type : application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . getAccessToken ( $credentials ) 
        ) 

        ) );

        $response=curl_exec($ch);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        print_r($response); 
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

[image: See its working fine for me]

Comment: I have added complete file.

Comment: I am not getting anything from your question. The same code is working for me. May I know from where you are calling thesse methods and where is the client implementations?

Comment: In localhost I have created a program.